# Перевести object в KeyValuePair<Tkey,Tvalue>

Tags: c#, key-value

У меня есть `object value`, его надо перевести в тип `KeyValuePair<Tkey,Tvalue>`
Пытался так:  `KeyValuePair <string, ObjectId> kvp = Id as KeyValuePair<string, ObjectId>;`
Пишет: Оператор `as` должен использоваться со ссылочным типом или с типом, допускающим значение `Null`(Тип `KeyValuePair<string, ObjectId>` не допускает значение `Null`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведение типов значений должно выполняться так:

```
KeyValuePair <string, ObjectId> kvp = (KeyValuePair<string, ObjectId>)Id;
```

Comment: Очень помогли! Большое спасибо! А не сможете объяснить почему именно так, если нетрудно

Comment: @VeNNoM, преобразование к типу в C# пишется в виде `(Type)expression`, при этом если `expression` преобразовать к требуемому типу невозможно - вызывается исключение. Оператор `as` же это как бы обёртка над обычным преобразованием, при его использовании исключения не происходит - в случае если преобразование невозможно - возвращается `null`. Но типы-значения (такие как `KeyValuePair` например) не могут иметь значения `null`, и следовательно использовать `as` с ними нельзя

Comment: О как, понял. Еще раз спасибо!